# Can't get MDX to work in a JavaScript Component. Just want Markdown to be turned to react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown

Trying to make a react component with MDX that will turn markdown into react components. I want this so I can transform a blog article with embedded components (such as special article toolings and diagrams) from markdown stored in the DB into something presented on the page.

Been working on it for a few hours now and even my best attempts just result in literally nothing being displayed on the page. Where replacing the 'content' with a string displays.

I'm 100% baffled, lost and confused and really would appreciate help.

Original problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/mbdz7k/reactmarkdown_custom_component_declaration_how/

Working solution (but I am struggling to get it to work on my end). Provided by cmdq
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-wescoff-ib8mv?file=/src/index.js

I've basically just moved the entire particular component file into being a JavaScript file but unfortunately I'm still running into many issues-- probably from lack of familiarality.

My current code is this in the file:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import renderToString from 'next-mdx-remote/render-to-string'
import hydrate from 'next-mdx-remote/hydrate'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const exampleMdx = `
# h1

**foo**

<MyCustomComponent text="hell yeah" />
a
bar
`

const components = {
  h1: (props) => <h1 style={{ color: 'tomato' }} {...props} />,
  MyCustomComponent: ({ text }) => <marquee>{text}</marquee>,
}


const functionThing = async () => {
    const mdxString = await renderToString(exampleMdx, {
        components,
    })
    return hydrate(mdxString, { components });
}


export const ArticleTextTrial = () => {
    let content = functionThing;
    console.log(functionThing());

    return (

        <div className="articleMainTextSectionBody">{exampleMdx}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Comparing your code and the example's, it's different. The code is missing the `main()` function to mount the React component to the root. Also, `hydrate()` should be in React component (`ArticleTextTrial`). I guess if you restructure to have the same amount of functions and structure, it'll work.